# First use of tableView.reloadRows is different

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

My cells stores an item and the amount of this item increases whenever tapped. To delete the amount the cell can be panned to the left and the amount is zero.

Whenever a cell has an item with `amount > 0`, a blue line (a `CAShapelayer`) is visible at the left side of the cell.

To set the amount back to `0` a function is called:

```
func deleteItem(_ index: IndexPath) {
    // Amount is set to 0

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
}
```

When the cell is reloaded, the blue line will be moved out of the cell. And because the blue line is a `CAShapeLayer`, it's implicit animation will kick in and animates the blue line going out of the cell.

Implicit animation:
[image: animating]

**Problem:**
However, the first time (after the view is loaded) this function is called, the blue line (`CAShapeLayer`) doesn't do the implicit animation.

No animation:
[image: No animation]

If I use `tableView.reloadData()` I won't have this problem, but instead it will reload the whole table even when I'm panning other cell's causing it to reset so I can't use `tableView.reloadData()`.

**Question:**
Why is it only the first time after the view has been loaded that the implicit animation of the blue line (`CAShapeLayer) isn't working? How can I make sure this implicit animation will always work?